# Image link in views exposed filter gallery

Tags: views, navigation, media

I created a content type which contains among other infos, some pictures

I'm using views with exposed filters to render them on the page (the images are thumbnails)

How can i create a link on the thumbnails that will start a gallery (big pop-up modal img slider) that include only the pictures in each content?

[Here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/580/picyza.jpg/) is what i can link pictures to atm (i'm looking for some other options for this drop down menu)

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a particular piece of content that has a set of photos that you want displayed in a gallery like fashion?  Is this correct?  Sorry I had trouble making out what you wanted from the description you gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  the [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module; it is great and very configurable, and it has also an image-format option for the Views module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Colorbox module to do this.
-Install Color Box
-Edit your view image field formatter to be Colorbox not Image. 
-Choose node style which would be displayed in the normal page
-Choose Colorbox style which would be displayed in the pop-up modal (colorbox, lightbox ...)
-In the Gallery Option (image grouping) Choose per page gallery ...

That's it